# How to reference $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] safely and efficiently in PHP

Tags: php, filter, scope, superglobals

To avoid using superglobals it seems I must use something like this:

`$doc_root = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');`

To get the document root. But without a filter specified this just does `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` ... what filter to use, is there a predefined filter for paths or do I need to make my own with regex.

Now that I've filtered the `$doc_root` do I refilter from the `$_SERVER` superglobal array everytime I want to use it? Or, should I declare `global $doc_root` inside of a function and then use that (or indeed is it better practice to reference the `$GLOBALS` array?)?

Comment: By using the magic constant `__DIR__`? Also the value for `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is defined in the server configuration. If you're paranoid of it being a the wrong value, you should look as to how it got changed in the server config.

Comment: *"To avoid using superglobals"* – stop right there. Why?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "avoid using '_unfiltered_ superglobals" - yes as  @ʰᵈˑ intimates I'm probably trying to be over-cautious. Why? Based on principle of always sanitizing inputs.
The question of whether a predefined filter for paths exists still stands. For the globals part assume it's an external variable, eg in $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad to use superglobals per se. But you should avoid them deep in your code as this adds hidden dependency on environment and makes the code harder to test.

So if you're concerned about this hidden dependency, you should take the value in your front controller and inject into the class using it. Or, if you're using a DI container you can define a service that returns this value.

Using `filter_input` function does not help here at all - it just hides the superglobal access.

Perhaps safer option is indeed using `__DIR__` constant.